# How can I animate an array of matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, animation, matrix, time

I have and array of matrixs in python, I would like to animate the complete sequence to observe the time evolution. How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide us with your current code, what you've tried so far, etc etc.

Comment: I tried to provide it, but this box does not allow, too long.

Comment: Any other option?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JuanRubei That is not a thing. Your posts can be as long as you want. There is no limit.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vZ96cE0zRQgsuMg7tGvl1Q5dSDjgak0s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I hope this work.

Comment: When I try to add a comment, it only allows around 550 characters